# how to use bitwise operator in python?

Tags: python

Description:
Input a list of numbers “num_list”.

All numbers in the list occur even times expect one number which occurs odd number of times. Find the number that occurs odd number of time in `O(1)` space complexity and `O(n)` time complexity.

Note: Use Bitwise operator.
Sample Input:

```
1 2 2 5 5 1 3 9 3 9 6 4 4
```

What I tried:

```py
def getOddOccurrence(arr, arr_size):
    for i in range(0, arr_size):
        count = 0
        for j in range(0, arr_size):
            if arr[i] == arr[j]:
                count += 1
        if (count % 2 != 0):
            return arr[i]
    return -1# driver code

arr = [1, 2, 2, 5, 5, 1, 3, 9, 3, 9, 6, 4, 4]
n = len(arr)
print(getOddOccurrence(arr, n))
```

Comment: using above question i need code in python

Comment: @OP if you post your code, we can help figure out the errors.

Comment: def getOddOccurrence(arr, arr_size):   
    for i in range(0,arr_size): 
        count = 0
        for j in range(0, arr_size): 
            if arr[i] == arr[j]: 
                count+=1    
        if (count % 2 != 0): 
            return arr[i]       
    return -1    
# driver code  
arr = [1,2,2,5,5,1,3,9,3,9,6,4,4 ] 
n = len(arr) 
print(getOddOccurrence(arr, n))

Comment: Please edit your post to show the code (don't use it in a comment).

Comment: @OP, I would suggest you add your code to the problem description. Its difficult to know what your code does without proper indentation.

Answer (score 0):

> Bitwise operations consists of multiple operations like AND, OR, XOR... and so on. The one you are looking for is called XOR.
> XOR of number with same number is 0. So if you XOR all elements in your array, all elements occurring even number of times cancel each other out. And you are left with with the number that occurred odd number of times.

Time Complexity: O(N)
Space Complexity: O(1)

```
def getOddOccurrence(arr, arr_size): 
       if len(arr) == 0:
          return -1
    
       xor = arr[0]
    
       for i in range(1, arr_size):
          xor = xor ^ arr[i]
    
       return xor
    
arr = [1,2,2,5,5,1,3,9,3,9,6,4,4 ] 
n = len(arr) 
print(getOddOccurrence(arr, n))
```